# Angular JS using ng-repeat to get in 3's then create a new row

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a table using ng-repeat, to 3 items in each row, then create a new row after, etc.

I am using a div span3, but it is not wrapping my bootstrap badges.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a range filter you can do nested repeats- the inner counting off the 3 items in your row and the outer counting off your rows (i.e. groups of three):

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:(data.length/3)+1">
    <span ng-repeat='item in data.slice($index*3,($index*3+3))'>
        {{item}}
    </span>
</div>
```

and the [associated range filter](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#more-about-loops) which returns an array that goes from 0 up to the specified parameter:

```
app.filter('range', function () {
  return function (input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
};
```